# Weird behavior when using + + in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

Everybody knows the basic concatenation of two strings in JavaScript:

```
> "Hello " + "World!"
'Hello World!'
```

But what happens if we use `+ +` instead of `+`? I just encountered the following *weird* behavior:

```
> "Hello " + + "World!"
'Hello NaN'
> "Hello " + + ""
'Hello 0'
```

From the examples above, I can see that the second string is converted into number. So, passing an object having `valueOf` property as function, the value returned by that function will be converted.

```
> "Hello " + + ({valueOf: function () {return 1; }})
'Hello 1'
```

As expected, it shows `"Hello 1"`.

---

Why is the second string converted in `Number`? Why not throwing a syntax error or so?

Comment: @jeremyharris Yep, but not `+ +` (`+ <space> +`).

Comment: evaluating + "" gives you zero

Comment: at all: got it, deleted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `+` is the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) whose purpose is to convert its operand to a number.

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers,
>   unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something
>   into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

```
"Hello " + + "World!"
```

can only be parsed as

```
"Hello " + (+ "World!")
```

which is

```
"Hello " + NaN
```

hence your result.

This unary operator is very useful in JavaScript and is one of the most common ways to convert from something which may be a number or a string to a number. It also has the advantage over `parseFloat` that it's not ridiculously tolerant (`parseFloat("7up")` would return `7`) which makes it an easy way to see if a string is the representation of a number (just test `s==+s`).

Comment: Indeed, can you explain why isn't it a syntax error?

Comment: Why would it be a syntax error ? `+somestring` is perfectly valid (see the doc I linked to)

Answer (score 2):

Great question. This is because JavaScript has a unary `+` operator (similar to the unary `-` as in, ex, `-1`, which is parsed to `- (1)`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)

Thus `"foo" + + "bar"` is parsed to `"foo" + (+ "bar")` (or if you prefer a lisp-style parse tree: `(+ "foo" (+ "bar")`).

The unary + converts its operand to a number, or `NaN` if the operand isn't a sensible number:

```
> +"42"
42
> +"foo"
NaN
```

Finally, adding a number (including `NaN`) to a string results in a string concatenation.

Thus `"foo" + +"bar"` can be expanded:

```
"foo " + +"bar"
"foo " + NaN
"foo NaN"
```

Comment: No, it's parsed as `("foo" + (+"bar"))`

Comment: Err, sorry, using lisp-style syntax; Will clarify

Answer (score 1):

Here `+` is a [*unary plus operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) Which tries to convert the operator in number & works as follows

```
+"" //return 0
+"Some" //returns NaN
```

So here

```
"Hello " + + "World!"
```

will be

```
"Hello " + (+ "World!")
"Hello " + NaN
"Hello Nan"
```